# Is there any keyboard shortcuts to go up and down the stack in Visual Studio 2010/2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to move up and down the current stack that I'm debugging using keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio 2010/2013.  Is this possible?

I've checked the Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard and filtered on the word *stack* and I've not found anything that looks like what I want.

Comment: Maybe you are over-thinking it a bit?  Use the up and down arrow keys, Enter to show the source.

Comment: @HansPassant No, I don't want to move to the stack pane, select the stack frame I want and press enter.  That is what a keyboard shortcut is for. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that I could switch to the stack pane using keyboard shortcut `Alt-7`.  Using [*AutoHotkey*](http://www.autohotkey.com/), I wrote the following script to map `Alt-Grey-Plus` and `Alt-Grey-Minus` to go up and down the stack.

```
!NumPadAdd:: Send !7{Up}{Enter}
!NumPadSub:: Send !7{Down}{Enter}
```

This is a work around.  Does anyone have a more direct method?